# Javascript-generated iframe displays on Chrome, but nowhere else

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

A JSFiddle would probably be the best way to explain this. http://jsfiddle.net/mTPwc/

I generate an iframe object from a Youtube URL using the following JS:

```
window.onload = loadviddy();

function loadviddy() {
    var page = document.getElementById('main');
    anchor_finder = new RegExp('[^<p>]*(<a href="([^"]+)">http([^<]+)</a>)');
    url_finder = /http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com\/watch\?v=|\.be\/)([\w\-\_]*)(&(amp;)?[\w\?=]*)?/;
    var video_id = page.innerHTML.match(url_finder);
    page.innerHTML = page.innerHTML.replace(anchor_finder, video_id[0]);
    var embed_code = '<div id="wrapper-rect"><div class="video"><div class="stretchy"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + video_id[1] + '?hd=1&amp;rel=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">This browser does not support iframes.</iframe></div></div></div>';
    page.innerHTML = page.innerHTML.replace(url_finder, embed_code);
}
```

It loads the iframe element on all browsers, but the iframe only displays on Chrome.

I've tested it on Firefox, Opera, Safari, and IE. None of them can load the video. Any clues as to what might be causing this?

Comment: Are you running with same protocol (http)? Your sample on jsfiddle works on all browsers on my laptop. I ran into similar issue before where there was a protocol mismatch. For my case, Chrome was the one having an issue.

Comment: `.stretchy {
    height: 0px;` ??? And remove protocol from iframe src http://jsfiddle.net/mTPwc/2/

Comment: It's the `height: 0`. It's a trick that should allow the height to scale in proportion to the width, but I guess it only works on Chrome.